# nuxt 3 production mode throws "process is not defined"

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am running a nuxt 3 app in non server mode `ssr: false`. It runs fine in development mode but as soon as I build the app via `npm run build` and then starting the server via `node .output/server/index.mjs` it comes up with a Error 500 screen saying `process is not defined`
There is no debug information, no console error and no error log on heroku either.

Here is my nuxt config:

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ['vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass', 'mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css', '@/assets/sass/main.sass'],
  build: {
    transpile: ['vuetify'],
  },
  // vite: {
  //   define: {
  //     'process.env.DEBUG': false,
  //   },
  // },
  modules: [
    ['@nuxtjs/axios', { proxyHeaders: false }],
    '@pinia/nuxt'
  ],
  ssr: false // Disable server side rendering
})
```

as you can see I also disabled the `vite` part as this is the only place in my code where `process` is even referenced.

This is the screen I see:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be on the nuxt axios module.
Removing the module and using default axios it seems to make it work.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your changes and setup with plain axios?

Answer (score 0):

I removed `@nuxtjs/axios` module and just use original `axios`. that works.

Answer (score 0):

i solve my case when i add process with yarn, and then add as a plugin.

So i did this:

```
yarn add process
```

and then create a process.ts file on my plugins folder:

plugins/process.ts

```
import process from "process"

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    globalThis.process = process
  })
```

[image]

and add on my nuxt.config.ts, i added the plugins section

```
import vuetify, { transformAssetUrls } from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/process'
  ],
  build: {
    transpile: ['vuetify'],
  },
  modules: [
    (_options, nuxt) => {
      nuxt.hooks.hook('vite:extendConfig', (config) => {
        // @ts-expect-error
        config.plugins.push(vuetify({ autoImport: true }))
      })
    },
    '@pinia/nuxt'
    //...
  ],
  vite: {
    vue: {
      template: {
        transformAssetUrls,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

[image]

On that project i am using Nuxt 3 + Vue 3 + Vuetify 3.

And on that way, was possible to deploy in Vercel and Netilify.